# Google maps Android API and current location

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am trying to implement the google maps API. I want to see my own position on the map and I want that it changes when I move significantly. The problem is that there are no errors but it does not display a marker of my position on the map. This is my onCreate() methode in the .java file

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
public static final String TAG = MapPane.class.getSimpleName();
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_pane);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}//onCreate
```

And this is the method I think I am missing here something

```
 public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Location services connected.");

    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "loc exists");
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }//if
    }//if
    else {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }//else
}//onConnected
```

because I never get into the second if statement. I guess I need the permission of the user first? Turning the gps on manually on my device does not work either. And the method below I used for displaying the marker on the map

```
private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("I am here!");
    mMap.addMarker(options);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

}//handleNewLocation
```

I used more methods but I think there is no flaw in there. In the AndroidManifest.xml I included

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: what's location's value?

Comment: It is null because I can see the "Log.i(TAG, "loc exists");" in my Android Monitor

Comment: did you add the methods onStart() and onStop() like this tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html?

Comment: did you get any error in your console?

Comment: This is the only error I got: "Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates.ModuleDescriptor" "

Comment: I do have an onStart() and onStop() method

Comment: about your error I found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328890/android-firebase-dynamitemodule-failed-to-load-module-descriptor

Comment: maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441384/fusedlocationapi-getlastlocation-always-null

Answer (score 0):

You can use LocationManager instead of google api client

```
             LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    final Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            //here you can get current position location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude();

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code is not providing any location to the`handlelocation()` method.

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
public static final String TAG = MapPane.class.getSimpleName();
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
LocationListener li;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_pane);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is reato be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)         getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

 li=new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };


  getHandledCurrentLocation();
}//onCr

private void getHandledCurrentLocation() {
    String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Log.e("LOCATION_DEBUG","LOCATION REQUESTED--- ");
    LCM.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 10 * 1000, 0,li);

}
private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
 Log.d(TAG, location.toString());
 double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
 double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
 LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

 MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
        .position(latLng)
        .title("I am here!");
 mMap.addMarker(options);
 mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

}//handleNewLocation
```

this code should work.

Answer (score 0):

I can see few issues with your code. I don't think you are handling the location updates provided by FusedLocationApi. I believe you are implementing `LocationListener`  even though that part of the code is not provided in your question. In that case you are implementing a method '`onLocationChanged(Location location)` ' in your activity.  This is the method in which you should try to set the new location on the map. Your `handleNewLocation` method will not be called by FusedLocationApi automatically

You may want to provide the complete code for your activity , then we can help you better.