# Unable to send data to firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to send data using firebase, but it says that DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
Here's my code. I checked but my problem doesn't resemble any other problems.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast.makeText(this, "heee", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    //editTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);

    textViewPersons = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPersons);

    firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


    buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Creating firebase object
            Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);

            //Getting values to store
            String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
           // String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString().trim();

            //Creating Person object
            Person person = new Person();

            //Adding values
            person.setName(name);
            //person.setAddress(address);

            //Storing values to firebase
            ref.child("Person").setValue(person);
        }
    });
}
```

I am stuck, please help!!

Comment: please check rules tab in firebase console of your application database '

Comment: and put it here

Comment: You have taken firebaseauth, you need to take ref. like  

Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase(URL);

Comment: you got my point ?

Comment: Not a good idea to mix legacy Firebase SDK 2.5.X, `Firebase.setAndroidContext()`, with new SDK 9.X.X, `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()`.  Change to use new SDK only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check "rules" in your firebase's console and then in database.
And change it to this:
{

"rules": {

```
".read": true,

".write":true
```

}

}
It should solve the problem.

Comment: OMG.. Finally! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Check your Google Play Services version - it will most likely be lower than the requirements (this recently caught me out when switching to the new API).

See also: [Android Firebase DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328890/android-firebase-dynamitemodule-failed-to-load-module-descriptor)