# Received Firebase Notification starts and closes android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

When I'm sending Firebase Notification from the Firebase console, it starts my splash screen and notification icon is appearing to the top of display. I have no idea what can cause this kind of behaviour. Any ideas?

this is my MyFirebaseMessagingService.class

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

    import com.Novatech.paybox.Activities.MainActivity;
    import com.Novatech.paybox.Activities.NewsActivity;
    import com.Novatech.paybox.Classes.News;
    import com.Novatech.paybox.R;
    import com.Novatech.paybox.SQLite.DBHandler;
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

    import java.util.List;

    public class MyFirebaseMessegingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

        String Title;
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            Intent intent  = new Intent(this, NewsActivity.class);
            if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){
                String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
                String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
                Title = title;
                System.out.println("TitleFrom MEssageingService::"+title);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("message",message);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
            }
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(Title);
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon());
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
        private int getNotificationIcon(){
            boolean userWhiteIcon = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
            return userWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.paybox_logo_transparant : R.drawable.paybox_logo;
        }
    }
```

and this is MyFirebaseInstanceIdService

```
import android.content.Context; 
import android.content.SharedPreferences; 
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId; 
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;


public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "REG_TOKEN";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);


       // Log.d(REG_TOKEN,recent_token);
       // System.out.println("REG_TOKEN::"+recent_token);
    } }
```

and this is my main activity where I redirect user to another activity if he/she taps on notification.

```
String notificationMessegaBody="a";

        if(getIntent().getExtras() != null){
            notificationMessegaBody = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
            System.out.println("MessageBody FromLoginChooserActivity::" + notificationMessegaBody);
            //insert news in SQLite Database
            if(notificationMessegaBody!="a"){
                if(!(notificationMessegaBody == null)){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginChooserActivity.this, NewsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("extras are empty");
        }
```

service inside AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <service
            android:name=".Notification.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".Notification.MyFirebaseMessegingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>-->
```

this is a logcat output

```
10-18 13:17:43.445 4691-4691/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-18 13:17:43.525 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
10-18 13:17:43.525 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox I/MultiDex: install
10-18 13:17:43.525 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
10-18 13:17:43.564 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox D/FirebaseApp: Initialized class com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.
10-18 13:17:43.571 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox D/FirebaseApp: Initialized class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.
10-18 13:17:43.579 4691-4753/com.Novatech.paybox E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Novatech.paybox-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.Novatech.paybox-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.Novatech.paybox-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
10-18 13:17:43.583 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.google.android.gms signature not valid.  Found: 
                                                                            MIIEQzCCAyugAwIBAgIJAMLgh0ZkSjCNMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMw
                                                                            EQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29n
                                                                            bGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5kcm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDAeFw0wODA4MjEyMzEz
                                                                            MzRaFw0zNjAxMDcyMzEzMzRaMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYw
                                                                            FAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29nbGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5k
                                                                            cm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDCCASAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggENADCCAQgCggEBAKtW
                                                                            LgDYO6IIrgqWbxJOKdoR8qtW0I9Y4sypEwPpt1TTcvZApxsdyxMJZ2JORland2qSGT2y5b+3JKke
                                                                            dxiLDmpHpDsz2WCbdxgxRczfey5YZnTJ4VZbH0xqWVW/8lGmPav5xVwnIiJS6HXk+BVKZF+JcWjA
                                                                            sb/GEuq/eFdpuzSqeYTcfi6idkyugwfYwXFU1+5fZKUaRKYCwkkFQVfcAs1fXA5V+++FGfvjJ/Cx
                                                                            URaSxaBvGdGDhfXE28LWuT9ozCl5xw4Yq5OGazvV24mZVSoOO0yZ31j7kYvtwYK6NeADwbSxDdJE
                                                                            qO4k//0zOHKrUiGYXtqw/A0LFFtqoZKFjnkCAQOjgdkwgdYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/T
                                                                            gt9r45jk14alMIGmBgNVHSMEgZ4wgZuAFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/Tgt9r45jk14aloXikdjB0MQswCQYD
                                                                            VQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNTW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzEUMBIG
                                                                            A1UEChMLR29vZ2xlIEluYy4xEDAOBgNVBAsTB0FuZHJvaWQxEDAOBgNVBAMTB0FuZHJvaWSCCQDC
                                                                            4IdGZEowjTAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4IBAQBt0lLO74UwLDYKqs6Tm8/y
                                                                            zKkEu116FmH4rkaymUIE0P9KaMftGlMexFlaYjzmB2OxZyl6euNXEsQH8gjwyxCUKRJNexBiGcCE
                                                                            yj6z+a1fuHHvkiaai+KL8W1EyNmgjmyy8AW7P+LLlkR+ho5zEHatRbM/YAnqGcFh5iZBqpknHf1S
                                                                            KMXFh4dd239FJ1jWYfbMDMy3NS5CTMQ2XFI1MvcyUTdZPErjQfTbQe3aDQsQcafEQPD+nqActifK
                                                                            Z0Np0IS9L9kR/wbNvyz6ENwPiTrjV2KRkEjH78ZMcUQXg0L3BYHJ3lc69Vs5Ddf9uUGGMYldX3Wf
                                                                            MBEmh/9iFBDAaTCK
10-18 13:17:43.583 4691-4753/com.Novatech.paybox V/GoogleSignatureVerifier: com.google.android.gms signature not valid.  Found: 
                                                                            MIIEQzCCAyugAwIBAgIJAMLgh0ZkSjCNMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMw
                                                                            EQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29n
                                                                            bGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5kcm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDAeFw0wODA4MjEyMzEz
                                                                            MzRaFw0zNjAxMDcyMzEzMzRaMHQxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQIEwpDYWxpZm9ybmlhMRYw
                                                                            FAYDVQQHEw1Nb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3MRQwEgYDVQQKEwtHb29nbGUgSW5jLjEQMA4GA1UECxMHQW5k
                                                                            cm9pZDEQMA4GA1UEAxMHQW5kcm9pZDCCASAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggENADCCAQgCggEBAKtW
                                                                            LgDYO6IIrgqWbxJOKdoR8qtW0I9Y4sypEwPpt1TTcvZApxsdyxMJZ2JORland2qSGT2y5b+3JKke
                                                                            dxiLDmpHpDsz2WCbdxgxRczfey5YZnTJ4VZbH0xqWVW/8lGmPav5xVwnIiJS6HXk+BVKZF+JcWjA
                                                                            sb/GEuq/eFdpuzSqeYTcfi6idkyugwfYwXFU1+5fZKUaRKYCwkkFQVfcAs1fXA5V+++FGfvjJ/Cx
                                                                            URaSxaBvGdGDhfXE28LWuT9ozCl5xw4Yq5OGazvV24mZVSoOO0yZ31j7kYvtwYK6NeADwbSxDdJE
                                                                            qO4k//0zOHKrUiGYXtqw/A0LFFtqoZKFjnkCAQOjgdkwgdYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/T
                                                                            gt9r45jk14alMIGmBgNVHSMEgZ4wgZuAFMd9jMIhF1Ylmn/Tgt9r45jk14aloXikdjB0MQswCQYD
                                                                            VQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNTW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzEUMBIG
                                                                            A1UEChMLR29vZ2xlIEluYy4xEDAOBgNVBAsTB0FuZHJvaWQxEDAOBgNVBAMTB0FuZHJvaWSCCQDC
                                                                            4IdGZEowjTAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4IBAQBt0lLO74UwLDYKqs6Tm8/y
                                                                            zKkEu116FmH4rkaymUIE0P9KaMftGlMexFlaYjzmB2OxZyl6euNXEsQH8gjwyxCUKRJNexBiGcCE
                                                                            yj6z+a1fuHHvkiaai+KL8W1EyNmgjmyy8AW7P+LLlkR+ho5zEHatRbM/YAnqGcFh5iZBqpknHf1S
                                                                            KMXFh4dd239FJ1jWYfbMDMy3NS5CTMQ2XFI1MvcyUTdZPErjQfTbQe3aDQsQcafEQPD+nqActifK
                                                                            Z0Np0IS9L9kR/wbNvyz6ENwPiTrjV2KRkEjH78ZMcUQXg0L3BYHJ3lc69Vs5Ddf9uUGGMYldX3Wf
                                                                            MBEmh/9iFBDAaTCK
10-18 13:17:43.587 4691-4753/com.Novatech.paybox E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Novatech.paybox-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.Novatech.paybox-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.Novatech.paybox-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
10-18 13:17:43.631 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox W/DynamiteLoaderImpl: Failed to load module version: module com.google.android.gms.flags not found
10-18 13:17:43.631 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:1 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:0
10-18 13:17:43.631 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.flags
10-18 13:17:43.636 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.crash.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Novatech.paybox-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.Novatech.paybox-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.Novatech.paybox-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
10-18 13:17:43.637 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.crash:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.crash:4
10-18 13:17:43.637 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.crash, version >= 4
10-18 13:17:43.647 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000a/n/armeabi-v7a
10-18 13:17:43.647 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000a/n/armeabi
10-18 13:17:43.657 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox I/FirebaseCrashApiImpl: FirebaseCrashApiImpl created by ClassLoader com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.DelegateLastPathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000a/DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodmnc_xxhdpi_release.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000a/n/armeabi-v7a, /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000a/n/armeabi, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]
10-18 13:17:43.665 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox W/DynamiteLoaderImpl: Failed to load module version: module com.google.android.gms.flags not found
10-18 13:17:43.665 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:1 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:0
10-18 13:17:43.665 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.flags
10-18 13:17:43.671 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
10-18 13:17:43.680 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox D/FirebaseCrashApiImpl: FirebaseCrash reporting API initialized
10-18 13:17:43.681 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox I/FirebaseCrash: FirebaseCrash reporting initialized com.google.firebase.crash.internal.zzg@f7ae0eb
10-18 13:17:43.681 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox D/FirebaseApp: Initialized class com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.
10-18 13:17:43.690 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 9080
10-18 13:17:43.690 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
10-18 13:17:43.690 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox D/FA: Debug logging enabled
10-18 13:17:43.690 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox D/FA: AppMeasurement singleton hash: 144412232
10-18 13:17:43.702 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox V/FA: Collection enabled
10-18 13:17:43.702 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox V/FA: App package, google app id: com.Novatech.paybox, 1:851374531660:android:13f39d9d52fa1182
10-18 13:17:43.710 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
10-18 13:17:43.711 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox D/FirebaseApp: Initialized class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.
10-18 13:17:43.711 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
10-18 13:17:43.714 4691-4774/com.Novatech.paybox V/FA: Using measurement service
10-18 13:17:43.715 4691-4774/com.Novatech.paybox V/FA: Connecting to remote service
10-18 13:17:43.722 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox I/GoogleConversionReporter: Already sent ping for conversion Cyh0CKfbimQQ8vyp2QM
10-18 13:17:43.783 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox V/FA: onActivityCreated
10-18 13:17:43.788 4691-4691/com.Novatech.paybox I/GAv4: Google Analytics 9.0.80 is starting up. To enable debug logging on a device run:
                                                           adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
                                                           adb logcat -s GAv4
```

Comment: if app is fully closed notification just starts app for a second and than it closes by itself

Comment: check this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328890/android-firebase-dynamitemodule-failed-to-load-module-descriptor

Comment: there is no any error or something like that in Logcat -  app is just starting to do stuff like ordinary launch

Comment: I've checked it , but that's not a problem with Play Services version.  I'm using version 9.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my application.java where I was starting SplashScreen activity which wasn't LAUNCHER activity. I made SplashScreen activity LAUNCHER and deleted it's starting method in application.java , that actually solved the issue.