# Image from SD storage to ByteArray

Tags: java, android, arrays

Edit:  I don't know how to convert an image file (example.jpg) to byteArray I am trying to understand how it is done but I got nothing so far, I have tried different methods found in this site but nothing seems to work for me. 
I have resulted in asking in here so I might be able to understand how it's done with the help of others

I have an image file in my sdcard and I know my path, now I want to take that image and convert it to byteArray, I am getting wrong results in my logcat or so I think I do. I am not sure how the output should be

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.awareness.snapshot.internal.Snapshot;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

import static android.R.attr.bitmap;
import static android.R.attr.duration;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    public byte[] B;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GPSTracker gps;
    public File imageFile ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }


    /**
     Create the map when the map is ready OnMapReady, The object GPS is ccalled (GPSTraccker) to obtain
     Values for lat and long.
     */
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        gps = new GPSTracker(MapsActivity.this);
        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        //adding an automated marker to mark the users spot on the map.
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Cyprus"));

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(19.0f));
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
          //When the map is clicked the following will occure

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                //create a new marker on the new lat/long of the spot clicked
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude)).title("New Marker");
                //places the marker
                mMap.addMarker(marker);
                //create an object of Bitmap
                Bitmap bitmap;
                //Creating and calling object Snapshot
                SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    //when the snapshot is ready do the following
                    public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    //Creating object Date and storing it to now
                        Date now = new Date();
                        //Retribing exact date and storing it to now
                        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);


                        try {
                            //dissabling strick mode for testing , remember to remvoe this code
                            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy old = StrictMode.getThreadPolicy();
                            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder(old)
                                    .permitDiskWrites()
                                    .build());

                            //mpath = /sd/date.jpg creating a dir for the image to be snaped
                            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";
                           //Calling object File.
                            File imageFile = new File(mPath);
                            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                            //outputing streaming to /imagefile
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);

                            Log.d("Var:OUT: ", " " + out);
                            Log.d("ImageFile" ,""+ imageFile) ;
                            Log.d("mPath" ,""+ mPath) ;
                            //decompose image
                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);

                            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(old);
                            ByteArrayOutputStream streams = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, streams);


                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
                            byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();
                            System.out.println("byte array:"+image);
                            Log.d("array", image.toString());
                            String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);
                            Log.d("array_Str",img_str);
                            System.out.println("string:"+img_str);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                mMap.snapshot(callback);


                System.out.println(point.latitude + "---" + point.longitude);


            }
        });

    }

  //  public byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
  //      ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  //      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, now);
  ////      Log.d("ARRAY", "" + now.toByteArray());
  //    byte[]  B = stream.toByteArray();

   //     return stream.toByteArray();

//}





    public void onSnapshotReady (Bitmap bitmap) {
        Date now = new Date();
        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);
        Log.d("DOulefko","test");
        try {
            // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

            // create bitmap screen capture
            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            File imageFile = new File(mPath);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void openScreenshot(File imageFile) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

My logcat (not including the entire base64)

> 11-15 11:46:25.565 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni 11-15 11:46:25.597
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/System: ClassLoader
>   referenced unknown path:
>   /data/app/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15-1/lib/arm64 11-15
>   11:46:25.600 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 I/MultiDex: VM
>   with version 2.1.0 has multidex support 11-15 11:46:25.600
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 I/MultiDex: install 11-15
>   11:46:25.600 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 I/MultiDex: VM
>   has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled. 11-15
>   11:46:25.603 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15
>   I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful 11-15
>   11:46:25.616 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/art: Before
>   Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter
>   android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter,
>   android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
>   would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable 11-15 11:46:25.622
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/PhoneWindow: state.preset
>   = false, color: 0, translucent = 0 11-15 11:46:25.622 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/PhoneWindow: state.preset
>   = false, color: 0, translucent = 0 11-15 11:46:25.622 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/PhoneWindow: state.preset
>   = false, color: 0, translucent = 0 11-15 11:46:25.624 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/PhoneWindow: state.preset
>   = false, color: -16777216, translucent = 0 11-15 11:46:25.629 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 V/BoostFramework:
>   mAcquireFunc method = public int
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquire(int,int[]) 11-15
>   11:46:25.630 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15
>   V/BoostFramework: mReleaseFunc method = public int
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockRelease() 11-15 11:46:25.630
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 V/BoostFramework:
>   mAcquireTouchFunc method = public int
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquireTouch(android.view.MotionEvent,android.util.DisplayMetrics,int,int[])
>   11-15 11:46:25.630 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15
>   V/BoostFramework: mIOPStart method = public int
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStart(int,java.lang.String)
>   11-15 11:46:25.630 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15
>   V/BoostFramework: mIOPStop method = public int
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStop() 11-15 11:46:25.632
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 V/BoostFramework:
>   BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@5ec1d49 11-15
>   11:46:25.632 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15
>   V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf =
>   com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@5eae64e 11-15 11:46:25.655
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/AppTracker: App Event:
>   start 11-15 11:46:25.662 19702-19717/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true 11-15
>   11:46:25.667 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/AppTracker:
>   App Event: stop 11-15 11:46:25.684
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/PhoneWindow: state.preset
>   = true, color: -16777216, translucent = 0 11-15 11:46:25.708 19702-19717/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build
>   : 19f8f74, Iac38d51750
>                                                                           Build Date                       : 06/06/16
>                                                                           OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.07.00.01
>                                                                           Local Branch                     : case2489916_Unmap_crash
>                                                                           Remote Branch                    : 
>                                                                           Remote Branch                    : 
>                                                                           Reconstruct Branch               :  11-15 11:46:25.712
>   19702-19717/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 I/OpenGLRenderer:
>   Initialized EGL, version 1.4 11-15 11:46:25.721
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/AbstractTracker: Event
>   success 11-15 11:46:25.725 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15
>   D/AbstractTracker: Event success 11-15 11:46:25.740
>   19702-19717/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 E/HAL: load:
>   gralloc.msm8996.so 11-15 11:46:37.663
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/AppTracker: App Event:
>   start 11-15 11:46:37.705 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15
>   D/AbstractTracker: Event success 11-15 11:46:38.715
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/LocationManager:
>   requestLocationUpdates
>   listener=com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15.GPSTracker@f1972c8
>   packageName= com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 11-15 11:46:38.718
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/Network: Network 11-15
>   11:46:38.735 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/AppTracker:
>   App Event: stop 11-15 11:46:38.749
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/PhoneWindow: state.preset
>   = false, color: 0, translucent = 0 11-15 11:46:38.749 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/PhoneWindow: state.preset
>   = false, color: 0, translucent = 0 11-15 11:46:38.749 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/PhoneWindow: state.preset
>   = false, color: 0, translucent = 0 11-15 11:46:38.750 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/PhoneWindow: state.preset
>   = false, color: -16777216, translucent = 0 11-15 11:46:38.757 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 I/zzai: Making Creator
>   dynamically 11-15 11:46:38.797
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/System: ClassLoader
>   referenced unknown path:
>   /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000e/n/arm64-v8a
>   11-15 11:46:38.818 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f:
>   Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
>   11-15 11:46:38.822 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15
>   I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version:
>   9877000 11-15 11:46:38.826 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15
>   I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version:
>   10084448 11-15 11:46:38.832 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15
>   W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation:
>   StrictModeDiskReadViolation 11-15 11:46:38.846
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f: Suppressed StrictMode
>   policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation 11-15 11:46:38.857
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f: Suppressed StrictMode
>   policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation 11-15 11:46:38.880
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f: Suppressed StrictMode
>   policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation 11-15 11:46:38.891
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f: Suppressed StrictMode
>   policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation 11-15 11:46:38.911
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f: Suppressed StrictMode
>   policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation 11-15 11:46:38.925
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f: Suppressed StrictMode
>   policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation 11-15 11:46:38.939
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f: Suppressed StrictMode
>   policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation 11-15 11:46:38.939
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f: Suppressed StrictMode
>   policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation 11-15 11:46:38.960
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f: Suppressed StrictMode
>   policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation 11-15 11:46:38.989
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f: Suppressed StrictMode
>   policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation 11-15 11:46:38.989
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 I/c: Token loaded from
>   file. Expires in: 430122644 ms. 11-15 11:46:38.989
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 I/c: Scheduling next
>   attempt in 429822 seconds. 11-15 11:46:39.018
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f: Suppressed StrictMode
>   policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation 11-15 11:46:39.019
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f: Suppressed StrictMode
>   policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation 11-15 11:46:39.032
>   19702-19924/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 I/DpmTcmClient:
>   RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor 11-15
>   11:46:39.073 19702-19954/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f:
>   Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
>   11-15 11:46:39.074 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f:
>   Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
>   11-15 11:46:39.075 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f:
>   Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation
>   11-15 11:46:39.083 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15
>   D/AppTracker: App Event: start 11-15 11:46:39.090
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/PhoneWindow: state.preset
>   = true, color: -16777216, translucent = 0 11-15 11:46:39.122 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/AbstractTracker: Event
>   success 11-15 11:46:39.137 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15
>   D/LocationManager: requestLocationUpdates
>   listener=com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15.GPSTracker@5f141d packageName=
>   com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 11-15 11:46:39.140
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/Network: Network 11-15
>   11:46:39.182 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15
>   D/AbstractTracker: Event success 11-15 11:46:39.195
>   19702-19717/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7fa01fdc00 (RippleDrawable) with handle
>   0x7f9b7feb80 11-15 11:46:39.942
>   19702-19973/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f: Suppressed StrictMode
>   policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation 11-15 11:46:40.120
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f: Suppressed StrictMode
>   policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation 11-15 11:46:40.121
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/f: Suppressed StrictMode
>   policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation 11-15 11:46:41.098
>   19702-19956/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/DynamiteModule: Local
>   module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates
>   not found. 11-15 11:46:41.115
>   19702-19956/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 I/DynamiteModule:
>   Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0
>   and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:2 11-15
>   11:46:41.115 19702-19956/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15
>   I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of
>   com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 2 11-15
>   11:46:41.117 19702-19956/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15
>   E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load DynamiteLoader:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$DynamiteLoaderClassLoader"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15-1/lib/arm64,
>   /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]] 11-15 11:46:41.117
>   19702-19956/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/DynamiteModule: Failed to
>   load remote module: Failed to get module context 11-15 11:46:41.118
>   19702-19956/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 W/DynamiteModule: Failed to
>   load module via fast routetn: Remote load failed. No local fallback
>   found. 11-15 11:46:41.119 19702-19956/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15
>   W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for
>   com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found. 11-15
>   11:46:41.124 19702-19956/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15
>   I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module
>   com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module
>   com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:2 11-15 11:46:41.125
>   19702-19956/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 I/DynamiteModule: Selected
>   remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version
>   = 2 11-15 11:46:49.625 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 I/System.out: 34.69429310156397---33.01508009433746 11-15 11:46:50.316
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/Var:OUT:: 
>   java.io.FileOutputStream@c4a6090 11-15 11:46:50.316
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/ImageFile:
>   /storage/emulated/0/Tue Nov 15 11:46:50 GMT+02:00 2016.jpg 11-15
>   11:46:50.317 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/mPath:
>   /storage/emulated/0/Tue Nov 15 11:46:50 GMT+02:00 2016.jpg 11-15
>   11:46:50.771 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 I/System.out:
>   byte array:[B@4772d89 11-15 11:46:50.772
>   19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/array: [B@4772d89 11-15
>   11:46:50.776 19702-19702/com.example.apostolis.gpsapi15 D/array_Str:
>   iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABDgAAAc4CAYAAADd+HYSAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAIABJREFU
>                                                                              eJzs3

Comment: So what is the question or the issue?

Comment: I cant get the bytearray .  I dont know waht i am doing wrong ..  
Or if am doing somethign wrong, can you pelase explain it to me

Comment: `I cant understand what I am doing wrong`. You did not explain what your code would have to do. First you should explain what you want to do exactly. Then post the code. Do not expect us to dig through your code in order to discover what should happen.

Comment: `I cant get the bytearray`. Of what? Again unclear what you can't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328890/android-firebase-dynamitemodule-failed-to-load-module-descriptor

try this.... your logcat has this issue.

Comment: I have edited the post. the code is trying to get the bytearray out of the map snapshot I have created and saved on my sdcard

Comment: `Image from SD storage`. Ok. But what does that have to do with `to get the bytearray out of the snapshot ` ? Which connection is there between snapshot and SD card?

Comment: `Image from SD storage`. You mean an image file on SD storage? You want to place a file from SD storage in a byte array? Is that what you want to do?

Comment: yes Exactly the one in imageFile i belive

Comment: `But I dont seem to get a bytearray out of the image I just created`.Why are you talking in that way? Why not: `But I dont seem to get a bytearray out of the file from SD card.` ? What does it matter how you created that file? Or who created that file? Or when? You just have a file isn't it?

Comment: yes I do, and I want to make to bytearray

Comment: Your code should be like this  //decompose image
                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: Can you confirm that the file is created in the external storage and you can view it? You are giving the extension as `jpg` and compressing as a `png`. Make them same. Also, close the output stream after you write your `Bitmap` to a file.

Comment: `yes I do, and I want to make to bytearray`. Ok. Then edit your post again and first tell us how you plan to do that. Start your post with 'I have an image file on sd card and i know the path to the file.'. (I still have not looked at your code and will not before you write down what your code should do).

Comment: I have edited again I hope its enough , I have explained my problem exactly I want the image to become bytearray

Comment: `I want the image to become bytearray`. I thought you wanted an image file to become a byte array. And further you did not explain how you were going to do that. So i will wait until you did.

Comment: I have edited it again.

Comment: You want to convert a `Bitmap` to `byte[]` or a `File` to `byte[]`?

Comment: A file to Bytearray

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `byte[]` from your `File` object using the below function.

```
byte[] fullyReadFileToBytes(File f) throws IOException {
        int size = (int) f.length();
        byte bytes[] = new byte[size];
        byte tmpBuff[] = new byte[size];
        FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(f);;
        try {
            int read = fis.read(bytes, 0, size);
            if (read < size) {
                int remain = size - read;
                while (remain > 0) {
                    read = fis.read(tmpBuff, 0, remain);
                    System.arraycopy(tmpBuff, 0, bytes, size - remain, read);
                    remain -= read;
                }
            }
        }  catch (IOException e){
            throw e;
        } finally {
            fis.close();
        }

        return bytes;
    }
```

After calling `bitmap.compress`, close the stream and pass your `imageFile` object to the above method like:

```
byte[] byteArray = fullyReadFileToBytes(imageFile);
Log.d("Activity", "Byte array: "+ Arrays.toString(byteArray));`
```