# my application in android studio has stopped after updated google play service

Tags: android, android-studio

I'am newbie in this field and I want to try develop food ordering application. Before this, my application just run smoothly, but when i update google play services, I got this error. I hope from your kindness to help me and teach me to solve this problem and share your knowledge. I will provide some information, and if i have lack of information, forgive me and please tell me.

This is the error in the logcat

```
04-11 07:01:40.128 6863-6882/com.example.user.letseatserver E/FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission.
04-11 07:01:39.459 6863-6883/com.example.user.letseatserver W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
04-11 07:01:39.460 6863-6883/com.example.user.letseatserver W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
04-11 07:01:39.460 6863-6883/com.example.user.letseatserver I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.crash:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.crash:0
04-11 07:01:39.462 6863-6883/com.example.user.letseatserver E/FirebaseCrash: Failed to load crash reporting
    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecw: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zzc: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecv.zzbvb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.crash.zzc.zzbuz(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.crash.zzd.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zzc: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzecv.zzbvb(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.firebase.crash.zzc.zzbuz(Unknown Source) 
        at com.google.firebase.crash.zzd.call(Unknown Source) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
04-11 07:01:39.466 6863-6885/com.example.user.letseatserver E/FirebaseCrash: Failed waiting for crash api to load.
    java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1016)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
        at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:248)
        at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.zzbut(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.crash.zza.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is my gradle project:

```
   buildscript {    
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven{
        url 'https://jitpack.io'
    }
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is the gradle:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user.letseatserver"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my menifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.user.letseatserver">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SignIn" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Try this **`implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.0'`**

Comment: @NileshRathod but i got the other error said "Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details." in implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0' have red-line

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328890/android-firebase-dynamitemodule-failed-to-load-module-descriptor

Comment: Thanks @AnuraagBaishya but all the solutions does not work for me. huaaaa